# sorting datagridview programmatically being error

Tags: c#, datagridview

hi i have datagridview name data1, and binding data to data1 from database, when i click the column header for sorting the data,,some error show up..the error like this "DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted".

this is sample of the code..

```
SomeDataContext db = new SomeDataContext();

data1.DataSource = db.data.ToList();


private void data1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)   
{     
      dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex],                
      ListSortDirection.Ascending);      
}
```

any solution guys??thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use the SortableBindingList class:

```
 SortableBindingList<person> persons = new SortableBindingList<person>();
 persons.Add(new Person(1, "timvw", new DateTime(1980, 04, 30)));
 persons.Add(new Person(2, "John Doe", DateTime.Now));

 this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
 this.ColumnId.DataPropertyName = "Id";
 this.ColumnName.DataPropertyName = "Name";
 this.ColumnBirthday.DataPropertyName = "Birthday";
 this.dataGridView1.DataSource = persons;
```

Comment: hi Joe Tuskan..this error show up when i use binding source "DataGridView control cannot be sorted if it is bound to an IBindingList that does not support sorting."..please help,,any solutions??

Comment: My mistake you need to implement a list in the following structure: http://www.timvw.be/2007/02/22/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt/